# Why are the exhaust plumes exiting the nozzles of SpaceShip Two segmented along their length?

Tags: nozzle, plume, development, exhaust

Here is a photo of SpaceShip 2's exhaust shortly after ignition during the test flight in January

[image]

Why do they have that segmented structure, and how does it affect thrust?

Comment: See [Mach Diamonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_diamond)

Answer (score 11):

Those are [Mach diamonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_diamond).  They form due to the interaction of the exhaust flow with its own supersonic shockwaves.  All rockets and some jet engines produce them; their visibility varies with the propellant combination, mixture ratio and environmental conditions.

The flow pattern doesn't appreciably affect thrust since it takes place after the exhaust has left the nozzle (where thrust is produced).